# R: RJDBC: Error to connecting Orientdb

Tags: r, jdbc, orientdb, rjdbc

I get error if I try to connect to OrientDB troth Orientdb JDBC in R 3.1.1 and RJDBC 0.2-4 package. The OrientDB is started i am able execute any SQL statments via OrientStudio. JDBC driver is in same directory as OrientDB libs are.

```
Error on .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/orientechnologies/orient/core/db/record/ODatabaseRecord
```

I use followed R code:

```
library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC(driverClass = "com.orientechnologies.orient.jdbc.OrientJdbcDriver", 
            classPath ="./orientdb-community-1.7.4/lib/orientdb-jdbc-1.7.jar" )
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:orient:remote://localhost/GratefulDeadConcerts", "admin", "admin")
```

Comment: did you get it to work? trying the same thing

Comment: @RicardoPietrobon Yes. You have to use the "ALL" JDBC Driver. This is irritating that OrietnDB have two different versions. By using "ALL" you are able to execute your SQL-Satements. Some times you can get a problem with `#' char if it is in results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [OrientDB JDBC Driver 1.7 ALL](http://www.orientechnologies.com/download) package.